# Fill JQuery UI Dialog From Server (Database)

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, web-services

I have Jquery Ui Dialog Like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
            x = e.pageX;
            y = e.pageY;
            $("#d").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                show: "blind",
                hide: "explode",
                position: [e.pageX, e.pageY],

                open: function (type, data) {
                    //Fill Dialog From Server
                }

            });
        });

        $("#c").bind("mouseover", function () {
            $("#d").dialog('open'); // open
        });
        $("#c").bind("mouseleave", function () {
            $("#d").dialog('close'); // open
        });
    });
</script>
```

How can i load some data from server dynamic ? in asp.net

Comment: Where do you want to load some data?

Comment: into JQuery Ui dialog for example label into dialog or etc

Comment: in case you're gonna switch to asp.net mvc look here http://awesome.codeplex.com/, at the Popup and PopupForm helpers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found solution

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function GetInfoByMprID(ByVal mprID As String) As String

    Return resualt
End Function

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
            x = e.pageX;
            y = e.pageY;
            $("#d").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                width: 'auto',
                show: "blind",
                hide: "explode",
                position: [e.pageX, e.pageY],

                open: function (type, data) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Constants.aspx/GetInfoByMprID",
                        data: "{'mprID': '" + 158 + "'}",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (msg) {
                            //alert(msg.d);
                            //$('lbl').val() = msg.d;
                            $("#d").empty();
                            $("#d").append('<p>' + msg.d + '</p>');
                        },
                        error: AjaxFailed
                    });
                }

            });
        });

        $("#c").bind("mouseover", function () {
            $("#d").dialog('open'); // open
        });
        $("#c").bind("mouseleave", function () {
            $("#d").dialog('close'); // open
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The call is fairly simple, just get ASP.Net to return *only* what content should be in the dialog, not an entire `<html>....</html>` page.  The load can be as simple as using [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/), like this:

```
open: function () {
  $(this).load("MyDialogContent.aspx");
}
```

...or it can be a web service call which an return either HTML or JSON, etc...you have a lot of options here.